# Android how to make a custom PopupWindow uncanceable

Tags: android, popupwindow

I created a class that extends PopupWindow. Is there any way to pretend the popup from getting canceld / making it uncanceable (like a dialog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
window.setTouchable(true);    
window.setFocusable(false); 
window.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Comment: OK, that pretends the window from being canceld if I touch the screen outside the window. But when I press the back-button the onBackPressed-callback of the underlaying Activity is called. Is there a way to fix that or does I have to handle this problem within the called onBackPressed-method?

Comment: you cannot call `setCancelable(false)` on a `PopupWindow`. That is only for `Dialog`

Comment: AFAIK, you need to handle `onBackPressed()`